# IBAN validation using ng-iban

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, iban

I am trying to do IBAN validation. Before this step, the user gets to input the country (5 countries in this case) and then when the user enters the IBAN, it should validate depended on the country selected. I am currently trying to use ng-iban with one country (BH), but can't seem to get it to work. Any help is appreciated and I am also open to using iban.js library if anyone can provide some helpful tips for that. My code for the country selection and IBAN field is included. Thanks!

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3 required">
            <label class ="control-label">Country of Treatment</label>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="formDetails.Country" ng-options="lookup.ID as lookup.NAME for lookup in lookupCountry" required>
            </select>
```

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3 required">
            <label class ="control-label" >iBAN</label>
            <input ng-model="formDetails.IbanNumber" ng-required= "formDetails.PaymentType == 'Wire' " ng-readonly="formDetails.PaymentType == 'Cheque'" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter iBAN Number" ng-iban="[BH]" >
        </div>
```

Comment: whats the problem ? Any console outputs ?

Comment: For some reason the country code wasn't working, it works fine without the country code.

Comment: If you need country code you can try this ng-iban-custom https://libraries.io/bower/ng-iban-custom